# I can't delete dom element 'img' in onclick function of Object

Tags: javascript

I write a simple bubble game(I create Array and he has bubble Objects) and Bubble has to burst, when I click it(so I delete dom img), but i can't apply to dom elemnt in function onclick. Why? How can I apply to my dom element(IMG) or how can I delete dom img in func onclick????

My Object "bubble"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sbHCr.png)

Google Chrome Inspector write...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JBft.png)

Full Code:

```js
function resize() {
    Grass.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    Grass.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    Grass.style.top = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 180 + 'px';
}
function bubble(id) {
    this.IMG = document.createElement('img');        
    this.IMG.src = './bubble.png';
    this.IMG.id = id;
    this.IMG.onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById(this.IMG.id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(this.IMG.id));
    }
    this.createBubble = function () {
        this.bubbleSize = Math.random() * (144 - 30) + 30;
        this.bomDiapozon = Math.random() * (75 - 55) + 55;

        this.IMG.style.width = this.bubbleSize + 'px';
        this.IMG.style.height = this.bubbleSize + 'px';
        this.xStart = Math.random() * document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        this.yStart = -Math.random() * document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        this.x = this.xStart;
        this.y = this.yStart;
        this.xSpeed = Math.random() * (9 + 9) - 9;
        this.ySpeed = Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1;
        this.flyWidth = Math.random() * (288 - 144) + 144;
    }
    this.createBubble();
    document.body.appendChild(this.IMG);
    this.fly = function () {
        if (this.y + this.bubbleSize >= document.documentElement.clientHeight - this.bomDiapozon) {
            this.createBubble();
        }
        if ((this.x >= this.xStart + this.flyWidth / 2) || (this.x <= this.xStart - this.flyWidth / 2)) {
            this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        }
        this.IMG.style.left = this.x + 'px';
        this.IMG.style.top = this.y + 'px';
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
    }
}
function go() {
        for (var i = 0; i < amountBubbles; i++) {
            bubbles[i].fly();
        }
}

document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
var amountBubbles = 30;
var bubbles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < amountBubbles; i++) {
    bubbles[i] = new bubble(i + 1);
}
var Grass = document.createElement('img');
Grass.src = './Grass.png';
document.body.appendChild(Grass);
resize();
setInterval(go, 40);
```

```css
img {
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: In the `createBubble` function add an id to each createdBubble

Answer (score 0):

You already have access to the event and node without needing to re-select it.  Try this:

```
this.IMG.onclick = function(event) {
  var parent = event.target.parentElement;
  parent.removeChild(event.target)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stalk Overflow!

In your anonymous function there is no context to `this`.

The snippet below binds `this` to that function, and it will be no longer undefined:

```
this.IMG.onclick = (function () {
    document.getElementById(this.IMG.id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(this.IMG.id));
}).bind(this)
```

Just notice how you wrap it with `()` and then add `.bind(this)` to it.

Another way to bind the context is by using an arrow function:

```
 this.IMG.onclick = () => {
        document.getElementById(this.IMG.id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(this.IMG.id));
    }
```

This arrow function binds `this`, `arguments` and `super` to your method.

Read more on arrow functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

See it working below with `.bind(this)`:

```js
function resize() {
    Grass.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    Grass.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    Grass.style.top = document.documentElement.clientHeight - 180 + 'px';
}
function bubble(id) {
    this.IMG = document.createElement('img');        
    this.IMG.src = './bubble.png';
    this.IMG.id = id;
    this.IMG.onclick = (function () {
        document.getElementById(this.IMG.id).parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById(this.IMG.id));
    }).bind(this)
    this.createBubble = function () {
        this.bubbleSize = Math.random() * (144 - 30) + 30;
        this.bomDiapozon = Math.random() * (75 - 55) + 55;

        this.IMG.style.width = this.bubbleSize + 'px';
        this.IMG.style.height = this.bubbleSize + 'px';
        this.xStart = Math.random() * document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        this.yStart = -Math.random() * document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        this.x = this.xStart;
        this.y = this.yStart;
        this.xSpeed = Math.random() * (9 + 9) - 9;
        this.ySpeed = Math.random() * (5 - 1) + 1;
        this.flyWidth = Math.random() * (288 - 144) + 144;
    }
    this.createBubble();
    document.body.appendChild(this.IMG);
    this.fly = function () {
        if (this.y + this.bubbleSize >= document.documentElement.clientHeight - this.bomDiapozon) {
            this.createBubble();
        }
        if ((this.x >= this.xStart + this.flyWidth / 2) || (this.x <= this.xStart - this.flyWidth / 2)) {
            this.xSpeed = -this.xSpeed;
        }
        this.IMG.style.left = this.x + 'px';
        this.IMG.style.top = this.y + 'px';
        this.x += this.xSpeed;
        this.y += this.ySpeed;
    }
}
function go() {
        for (var i = 0; i < amountBubbles; i++) {
            bubbles[i].fly();
        }
}

document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
var amountBubbles = 30;
var bubbles = [];
for (var i = 0; i < amountBubbles; i++) {
    bubbles[i] = new bubble(i + 1);
}
var Grass = document.createElement('img');
Grass.src = './Grass.png';
document.body.appendChild(Grass);
resize();
setInterval(go, 40);
```

```css
img {
    position:absolute;
}
```